# Change position of submenus in a QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmenu

In my project, I have a QMenu with a submenu item. The submenu has a lot of items so it's height is relatively large.

I want to vertically center the submenu relative to the item that executed the submenu.

I have already subclassed the submenu I want to reposition and tried changing the geometry on "aboutToShow" just to test things, but this has no effect:

```
class MySubMenu : public QMenu
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QuickMod();
    ~QuickMod();

private slots:
    void centerMenu();
};



MySubMenu::MySubMenu()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), this, SLOT(centerMenu()));
}

MySubMenu::~MySubMenu()
{
}

void MySubMenu::centerMenu()
{
    qDebug() << x() << y() << width() << height();
    setGeometry(x(), y()-(height()/2), width(), height());
}
```

Here is an image I quickly MS Painted that I hope visually explains what I'm trying to achieve: (Before and After)
[image]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aboutToShow` is emited before the geometry is updated so the changes are overwritten later. The solution is to change the position an instant after they are displayed, for this we can use a `QTimer` with a small time.

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QTimer>

class CenterMenu: public QMenu{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CenterMenu(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QMenu{parent}{
        connect(this, &CenterMenu::aboutToShow, this, &CenterMenu::centerMenu);
    }
    CenterMenu(const QString &title, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR): QMenu{title, parent}{
        connect(this, &CenterMenu::aboutToShow, this, &CenterMenu::centerMenu);
    }
private slots:
    void centerMenu(){
        QTimer::singleShot(0, [this](){
            move(pos() + QPoint(0, -height()/2));
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;

    auto fileMenu = new QMenu("Menu1");
    w.menuBar()->addMenu(fileMenu);
    fileMenu->addAction("action1");
    fileMenu->addAction("action2");
    auto children_menu = new CenterMenu("children menu");
    children_menu->addAction("action1");
    children_menu->addAction("action2");
    children_menu->addAction("action3");
    children_menu->addAction("action4");
    children_menu->addAction("action5");
    children_menu->addAction("action6");
    fileMenu->addMenu(children_menu);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Note that I had to change the timer code to the traditional SLOT() notation instead of the [this]() to get it compiling for my environment. Weird little trick :)

Comment: @mrg95 Are you using Qt4?

Comment: Nope. Qt 5.6.2 but compiling with msvc2010

Comment: @mrg95 in Qt5 the SLOT notation is old, it is considered a bad practice, it is recommended to use the new syntax, if you are using Qt5 add `CONFIG += c++11` in your .pro, http://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax